# How to create an if-else in which you can not pass to other activity unless at least 1 radiobutton is selected. Tried too times but still I don't know

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, radio-button

Hello i am fairly new in kotlin and I am having a little problem. I am trying to make a button that went you click you pass to other activity but only if one of the three radioButtons is selected. I did this code but it doesn't work:

```kotlin
button.setOnClickListener {
    if (!radioButton1.isChecked || radioButton2.isChecked || radioButton3.isChecked) {
        // throws Toast
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Thee radiobuttons are inside of a radioGroup.

Comment: Do you mean at least one, or exactly one needs to be checked, and does it matter which one is checked?

Comment: It doesn't matter which of the radioButtons is checked, but at least 1 must be checked to move on to the next activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is checking if the first button is *not* checked or if the second or third buttons *are* checked. So, the only condition in which the activity will be started is if the first button is checked and the second and third buttons are not checked.

So, corrected logic would be:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    if (!radioButton1.isChecked && !radioButton2.isChecked && !radioButton3.isChecked) {
        // throws Toast
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Semantically, you would read it as, "if the first button is not checked, and the second button is not checked, and the third button is not checked, show the toast, and otherwise start the activity."

Since this is a confusing way to word it, I would reverse the if/else branches so it's easier to understand. It's usually easier to think about logic without nots (`!` operators).

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    if (radioButton1.isChecked || radioButton2.isChecked || radioButton3.isChecked) {
        val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        // show Toast
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use a list and the `any` function:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val radioButtons = listOf(radioButton1, radiouButton2, radioButton3)
    if (radioButtons.any { it.isChecked }) {
        val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        // show Toast
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I couldn't fix it for a while and I didn't know why!  I used the last method you put and it is the one I needed!